# SQL date overlap

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'd like to select only the id of staffs who have had more than one position but only hold one at any given time. If end date is NULL, it means that it is his/her current position.

For the example below, I'd like to get 1, 3.

```
 id |   position   |  start_date  |  end_date 
----------------------------------------------
  0 | staff        | 2005-01-01   | 2006-01-01
  0 | secretary    | 2006-01-02   | 
  0 | assistant    | 2006-01-02   |
  1 | staff        | 2005-01-01   | 2006-01-01
  1 | assistant    | 2006-01-02   |
  2 | receptionist | 2005-01-01   | 
  3 | driver       | 2005-01-01   | 2007-01-01
  3 | operator     | 2007-01-02   | 
  3 | intern       | 2002-01-01   | 2002-03-01
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be approached in two ways. If you really only need the IDs, then doing a two step query is one option.

First get all rows that have more than one position:

```
select s1.id
from staff s1
where exists (select 1 
              from staff s2
              where s1.id = s2.id
              and s1.position <> s2.position)
```

To get those that had more than one position at the same time you can use:

```
select s1.id
from staff s1
where exists (select 1
              from staff s3
               where s1.id = s3.id
                 and s1.position <> s3.position
                 and (s1.start_date, coalesce(s1.end_date, 'infinity'::date)) overlaps (s3.start_date, coalesce(s3.end_date, 'infinity'::date))
             )
```

As `null` can't be compared, we need to replace the `null` values in the `end_date` with a date that is greater than all other dates. This is what `coalesce(s3.start_date, 'infinity'::date)` does. The `overlaps` operator checks for overlapping date ranges. Using something like `date '9999-12-31'`  in the coalesce would also work, but using `infinity` makes this more explicit (at least in my eyes)

When you combine these with the `EXCEPT` operator, you get the desired result:

```
select s1.id
from staff s1
where exists (select 1 
              from staff s2
              where s1.id = s2.id
              and s1.position <> s2.position)

except

select s1.id
from staff s1
where exists (select 1
              from staff s3
               where s1.id = s3.id
                 and s1.position <> s3.position
                 and (s1.start_date, coalesce(s1.end_date, 'infinity'::date)) overlaps (s3.start_date, coalesce(s3.end_date, 'infinity'::date))
             )
;
```

For your sample data the above query will return:

```
id
--
 1
 3
```

---

If you need all columns and all positions (instead of *only* the IDs), you can take a different approach.

First get all rows that do not have overlapping positions:

```
select s1.*
from staff s1
where not exists (select 1
                  from staff s2
                  where s1.id = s3.id
                    and s1.position <> s3.position
                    and (s1.start_date, coalesce(s1.end_date, 'infinity'::date)) overlaps (s2.start_date, coalesce(s2.end_date, 'infinity'::date))
             )
```

The above will also include the row with id = 0 with the no longer active position, so we need to remove all those rows that have more than one position:

```
select *
from (
  select s1.*, 
         count(*) over (partition by s1.id) as cnt
  from staff s1
  where not exists (select 1
                    from staff s2
                    where s1.id = s2.id
                      and s1.position <> s2.position
                      and (s1.start_date, coalesce(s1.end_date, 'infinity'::date)) overlaps (s2.start_date, coalesce(s2.end_date, 'infinity'::date))
                )
) t
where cnt > 1;
```

For your sample data the above will return:

```
id | position  | start_date | end_date   | cnt
---+-----------+------------+------------+----
 1 | staff     | 2005-01-01 | 2006-01-01 |   2
 1 | assistant | 2006-01-02 |            |   2
 3 | driver    | 2005-01-01 | 2007-01-01 |   3
 3 | operator  | 2007-01-02 |            |   3
 3 | intern    | 2002-01-01 | 2002-03-01 |   3
```

---

I am not sure if these are the most efficient ways to do it, but I can't think of something else right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- First select all id's that have held more than one position: 0, 1, 3
SELECT id
FROM personnel
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) > 1

EXCEPT

-- Now remove id's that had an overlap in positions: 0
SELECT DISTINCT sub1.id
FROM (
  SELECT id, position, daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') AS period
  FROM personnel) sub1
JOIN (
  SELECT id, position, daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') AS period
  FROM personnel) sub2 
ON sub1.id = sub2.id AND sub1.period && sub2.period AND sub1.position <> sub2.position;
```

[**SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d5755)

This makes use of [the `daterange` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html), which is always handy to use when you have a starting and an ending date as it allows to check for overlaps with the `&&` operator.